# XSLT as simple HTML template engine on multiple files run from ant

Tags: html, templates, xslt, ant

I'm looking for an alternative to the [dreamweaver templates](https://helpx.adobe.com/dreamweaver/topics/templates.html) on my website as I've moved to Aptana. I looked at various template engines but found the content blocks generally had to be defined in string variables to be injected into the template, or in a file with proprietary tags. I didn't like large blocks of HTML code in quotes/heredoc because they're fairly ugly (mixing presentation mark-up with code that applies templates), and have no syntax highlighting or auto-completion. I didn't like proprietary tags because again the editor won't understand them.

Since my needs are only for a simple static HTML templates I thought XLST might do the trick. My plan was to merge content files with a template using XSLT, run from ant as an [automatic project builder](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/gettingStarted/qs-93_project_builder.htm) whenever I save a file.

I started with this template - template.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html data-template="template">
    <head>
        <style>
            .column{ width: 25%; background: lightgrey }
            #left { float: left; }
            #header { background: lightblue }
            #footer { background: lightblue; clear: both }
        </style>
        <title id="title" data-template="block">Default title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="header">
            header content
            <div id="search" data-template="block"> default search.. </div>
        </div>
        <div id="left" class="column">
            <div id="leftcontent" data-template="block"> Default left column content </div>
            <div id="advert"> advert... </div>
        </div>
        <div id="main" data-template="block"> Default main content </div>
        <div id="footer"> footer content </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Where "data-template='block'" denotes a block who's content can be overriden in a page. The style, header, advert, and footer can't be changed.

I then defined a content page with id's matching the blocks to replace - index.content.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title id="title">index title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="leftcontent">Left column content for index here...</div>
        <div id="main"><b>Main content for index here...</b></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I like the fact that both my template and content are plain HTML, so I get syntax highlighting, auto-completion, and I can view them in a browser.

I then have this simple XSLT which goes through the template file, and replaces any blocks defined in the content file - apply-template.xslt:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<xsl:transform version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html" doctype-system="about:legacy-compat" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:param name="contentFile"/>
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*[name()!='data-template']"/>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="current()/@data-template='block' and document($contentFile)//*[@id=current()/@id]">
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="document($contentFile)//*[@id=current()/@id]/node()" />
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" />
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

and I run it from this ant file:

```
<project name="commutefrom" default="apply-templates" basedir=".">
  <target name="apply-templates">
      <xslt in="template.html" out="output/index.html" extension=".html" style="apply-template.xslt">
         <param name="contentFile" expression="input/index.content.html"/>
       </xslt>
  </target>
</project>
```

Which produces this output (reformatted) - index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html SYSTEM "about:legacy-compat">
<html>
    <head>
        <META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <style>
            .column{ width: 25%; background: lightgrey }
            #left { float: left; }
            #header { background: lightblue }
            #footer { background: lightblue; clear: both }
        </style>
        <title id="title">index title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="header">
            header content
            <div id="search">default search..</div>
        </div>
        <div id="left" class="column">
            <div id="leftcontent"> Left column content for index here... </div>
            <div id="advert"> advert... </div>
        </div>
        <div id="main"> <b>Main content for index here...</b> </div>
        <div id="footer"> footer content </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Great!

Now my problem is that of course my website has multiple pages. So I want to apply this process to all of them. For each content file, the input would always be template.html, and the contentFile parameter would be the content file. Whilst the ant XSLT task allows for running over multiple files (with basedir), that would make the each file the input.

**So, how can I run the XSLT for each content file, but with the input always template.html, and the parameter being the content file?**

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

I'm no ant expert, but I assume that it has the ability to process all the files in a folder.
I would advise you to author your templates in xslt rather than as html - you'll have much more power and flexibility. You'll get syntax highlighting and auto-completion with any xml/xslt aware editor.